# Given the results of a POST, how can I change a value and resubmit it?

Tags: php, html

Say I have a HTML form that lets you input a name and age and returns with a list of people with that name and age.

```
<form method="post" action="/search_results">
   <input type="text" name="personName">
   <input type="text" name="personAge">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

And on the search results page I have a list of the results, but I only display 50 at a time and allow users to go forwards/backwards between the page with buttons. So the results page would also look for a POSTed 'pageNumber' value and default to 0 if there is none.

When they click a button, how would I resubmit the age and name and also submit the corresponding pageNumber from the button?

I'm using PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="/search_results">
  <input type="text" name="personName" value="<?php echo (isset($formdata['personName'])?$formdata['psersonName']:"") ?>">
  <input type="text" name="personAge" value="<?php echo (isset($formdata['personAge'])?$formdata['personAge']:"") ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentPage" value="<?php echo (isset($formdata['currentPage'])?$formdata['currentPage']:"0") ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

formdata are the data which are the inputs of the previous submit. These data should be returned by the search_results page along with the view.

Below is the js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".paginationBtns").click(function(){
            var page = $(this).attr('pageValue');

            $("input[name='current']").val(page);

            $("form").submit();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Assumptions of the forward and backward button

```
<a href="#" pageValue=0>Back</a><a href="#" pageValue=50>Next</a>
```

You have to append the back and next pageValue while loading each page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field to the form:

```
<form name=search"" method="post" action="/search_results">
  <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber"
    value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pageNumber']) ? (int) $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="personName">
   <input type="text" name="personAge">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Add a JavaScript function to modify the hidden field value:

```
<script>
function search(pageNumber) {
  var form = document.forms.search;
  if (!form) return;
  form.elements.pageNumber.value = pageNumber;
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Apply the JavaScript function for the page buttons:

```
<span onclick="search(1)">1</span>
<span onclick="search(2)">2</span>
```

Obviously, the buttons should be generated with PHP in the following manner:

```
<?php
for ($p = 0; $p < $pagesNum; ++$p) {
  echo "<span onclick='search($p)'>$p</span>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in pagination to use a simple link that contains the parameres (GET) and not (POST). That way, when you have the parameters in the url you can cache it, add to favorites, get indexed by google, share your page in email/facebook etc.

```
<a href='http://example.com/?personName=<?=$_POST['personName']?>&personAge=<?=$_POST['personAge']?>&page=<?=$next_page_number?>'>Next</a>
```

If for some reason you must or really want to use POST you can save the values in hidden inputs within a form in the page and then sumbit it when clicking on "next page" button.

Form example:

notice its just an example you should sanitize the variables and not put them directly from the $_POST

```
<form name="pagination" method="post" action="/search_results">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="personName" value='<?=$_POST['personName'];?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="personAge" value='<?=$_POST['personAge'];?>'>
</form>
```

notice that we set the next page numbers & do submit by using a command from the form of:

```
<button onclick='document.getElementById("page").value= "2";document.pagination.submit();'>Next page</button>
```